# Web3.js BigNumber not working for large power exponent

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am getting the error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion failed

specifically where it's checking inside of BN.js:

```
function assert (val, msg) {
    if (!val) throw new Error(msg || 'Assertion failed');
}
```

I am receiving a number to the power of 29, which is meant to have 18 decimal places, that I want to convert into a "non-decimal" number similar with wei and eth:

```
const post_response_2 = await fetch('/balanceOf-TKN-by-addr', {method: 'POST', body: stringify_post_input, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } });
var TKN_balance_response = await post_response_2.json(); 
console.log(TKN_balance_response);
var TKN_BN = await new BN(TKN_balance_response).toString();      //line giving error
var TKN_balance = await web3.utils.fromWei(TKN_BN, 'ether');
console.log("TKN_balance :: "+String(TKN_balance));
```

On my server side, I get the response of `988699999999999976500000000000`, and in the client console.log above, I see `9.886999999999999e+29`.

What am I doing wrong with `BN.js`?

Since there are 18 decimal places, I expect the answer for this that I console.log to be `988699999999.999976500000000000`, then I'd round be able to round it, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BN.js doesn't accept values in the exponential form (in your case the `9.886999999999999e+29`).

You can convert the expenential form to a string representing of the full number using the `.toLocaleString()` native function.

```
// type `Number`
const TKN_balance_response = 9.886999999999999e+29;
// type `string`
const TKN_balance_response_string = TKN_balance_response.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false});
var TKN_BN = await new BN(TKN_balance_response_string).toString();
console.log(TKN_BN);
```

prints

```
988699999999999900000000000000
```

---

A cleaner solution would be to return the (large number) value from `/balanceOf-TKN-by-addr` endpoint already as a string (my guess based on the context is that it's returned as a Number or it's converted to Number by the `json()` function). Then you could pass it to the `BN.js` constructor as is:

```
const TKN_balance_response = '988699999999999976500000000000';
var TKN_BN = await new BN(TKN_balance_response).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
const { toBn } = require('evm-bn')
const ethers = require('ethers')

const ToWei = (amount, decimals) => {
   return ethers.BigNumber
       .from(toBn(amount.toString(), decimals)._hex).toString()
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.